# How to turn off screen under Linux/BSD?

Tags: power-management, monitors

How can I turn off my laptops screen from software side? ex.: under Scientific-linux, OpenBSD? Or the best I can do from OS side is just to show a black picture? Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
xset dpms force off
```

works for most X setups.